# Play Audio Stream Using Windows APIs in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, directshow, ms-media-foundation

To play an `.mp3` file in Windows using (in this case) DirectShow you only need:

```
#include <dshow.h>
#include <cstdio>
// For IID_IGraphBuilder, IID_IMediaControl, IID_IMediaEvent
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib") 

const wchar_t* filePath = L"C:/Users/Public/Music/Sample Music/Sleep Away.mp3";

int main()
{
    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent   *pEvent = NULL;

    // Initialize the COM library.
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return 0;
    }

    // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
    hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::printf("ERROR - Could not create the Filter Graph Manager.");
        return 0;
    }

    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);

    // Build the graph.
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(filePath, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Run the graph.
        hr = pControl->Run();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Wait for completion.
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);

            // Note: Do not use INFINITE in a real application, because it
            // can block indefinitely.
        }
    }
    // Clean up in reverse order.
    pEvent->Release();
    pControl->Release();
    pGraph->Release();
    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

I can't find a way to have something like this, but to be able to play an `.asx` instead, like for example: http://listen.radiotunes.com/public5/solopiano.asx

In MSDN I can only find ways to do this in C# making a Forms application and inserting a WindowsMediaPlayer control in a form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

An `.asx` file is actually a playlist. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Stream_Redirector) some information about the format.

`.asx` is not supported by DirectShow. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407173(v=vs.85).aspx) for the supported formats.

You might parse the file, as it is XML, and find the actual URL of the stream, and then play it, or you could use the Windows Media Player SDK. You can see some sample code for WM SDK [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564119(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Ah, ok, that explains it. I'm trying [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564579(v=vs.85).aspx) --- but how do I use that control in the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564119(v=vs.85).aspx) in C++ (that is JScript I think)...

Comment: WM sdk should contain a c++ api also. You should check the docs and headers.

Comment: Yes, `IWMPPlayer` does the job quite well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it to work with this example taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd564579(v=vs.71).aspx) and adding this extra line: `hr = spPlayer->put_URL(L"http://listen.radiotunes.com/public5/solopiano.asx");`:

```
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "atlwin.h"
#include "wmp.h"
#include <cstdio>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComBSTR bstrVersionInfo; // Contains the version string.
    CComPtr<IWMPPlayer> spPlayer;  // Smart pointer to IWMPPlayer interface.



    hr = spPlayer.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = spPlayer->get_versionInfo(&bstrVersionInfo);
        hr = spPlayer->put_URL(L"http://listen.radiotunes.com/public5/solopiano.asx");

    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Show the version in a message box.
        COLE2T pStr(bstrVersionInfo);
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCSTR)pStr, _T("Windows Media Player Version"), MB_OK);
    }

    // Clean up.
    spPlayer.Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not ask another question inside an answer. Post it as another question.

Comment: @JonathanPotter OK, removed.